# How can I open a file only if it is not already open, in Perl?

Tags: perl, file, subroutine

If I have a subroutine that opens a file what is the best way to ensure it opens it only upon the first time the subrountine is called?  I have this but not sure if its best practice:

```
{
my $count = 0;
sub log_msg {
    my ($msg,$name) = @_;

    if ($count == 0) {
        my $log_file_name = "/tmp/" . $name;
        open my $log_fh,">",$log_file_name or  croak "couldn't open $log_file_name : $!";
        print $log_fh "$timestamp: created and opened $log_file_name\n";
    }
    $count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why you would have a "log_msg" sub that is only supposed to log a message the first time it's called.

Comment: of course I wouldn't want that .... this is incomplete code.....had to strip out a bunch of stuff to publish on here....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like a good reason to use a state variable. Store the filehandles in a persistent hash.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings;

sub log_msg {
  state %fh;
  my ($msg, $name) = @_;

  unless ($fh{$name}) {
    warn "Opening $name\n";
    open $fh{$name}, '>', $name or die $!;
    print {$fh{$name}} scalar localtime, " Opened file\n";
  }

  print {$fh{$name}} $msg, "\n";
}

log_msg('Message1', 'first.log');
log_msg('Message2', 'first.log');
log_msg('MessageA', 'second.log');
log_msg('MessageB', 'second.log');
```

Note the extra set of braces around the filehandles in the print call. That's because print is a bit picky about what you can use as its filehandle argument.

Comment: If you need compatibility with 5.8 (which doesn't have `state` variables), you can use a `my` var outside the sub instead (just like `$count` in ennuikiller's example).

Comment: `use feature "state";` should do the trick in 5.8 and beyond.

Comment: I show a per-5.10 example, but I wouldn't use state() here anyway since I'd refactor this into a sub that prints the log message and one that keeps track of the filehandles.

Answer (score 3):

The best way is to use [Log::Log4perl](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Log-Log4perl) so you don't have to think about it and you can focus on your real task.

Aside from that, you can use some of the tricks for files and filehandles that we cover in *Effective Perl Programming*. Luckily for you, that's also the [free chapter](http://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/blog/263) that our publisher gives away.

In short, you don't want to think about that in your logging routine. It's cluttercode. Instead, create a method that either returns the cached filehandle or opens it (this is a lot like a method you'd use to ping a database handle and reconnect if needed):

```
 sub log_msg {
      my( $self, $msg, $name ) = @_;

      print { $self->get_fh_by_name( $name ) } $msg;
      }

 BEGIN { # to define variables before the subroutine
 my %log_fhs;
 sub get_fh_by_name {
     my( $self, $name ) = @_;

     return $log_fhs{$name} if defined $log_fhs{$name};

     open my $log_fh, catdir( $base_dir, $name ) or croak "...";
     print $logfh ...

     $log_fhs{$name} = $log_fh;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, for starters, the `$count++` should go inside your if statement and can be changed to simply `$count=1`. You may also want to rename $count to `$file_opened_flag` or something more meaningful, as well. Other than that, I see nothing wrong with this.

Comment: I see. Well, hopefully the rest of my answer helps to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anything wrong with using per se but if there is really only 1 file to track, why not just keep `$log_fh` in the closure and use `if(!$log_fh->opened())` instead of a count variable?